# Puddles created by rain

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, weather

When it rains, puddles are formed on the streets.
Is there a classical Latin word for such a small puddle?
The only two examples of "puddle" in L&S are *fetutina* (a dirty and stinking puddle) and *lustrum* (more like a swamp), and both seem to be off the mark.
After more searching, I found [*stagnum*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=stagnum1&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) and [*lacuna*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DL%3Aentry+group%3D3%3Aentry%3Dlacuna), but neither seems to hit the nail on the head.
Perhaps *stagnum* sounds most promising, but what word was actually used in classical Latin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of the small puddles that collect after rain, classical Latin seems to prefer *a small collection of water*.  For example, Lucretius uses ***conlectus aquae*** of a shallow puddle between paving stones, much as one would find after a recent downpour:

> *At **conlectus aquae** digitum non altior unum,
>
>   qui lapides inter sistit per strata viarum,
>
>   despectum praebet sub terras impete tanto,
>
>   a terris quantum caeli patet altus hiatus,
>
>   nubila despicere et caelum ut videare et aperta
>
>   corpora mirande sub terras abdita cernas.*
>
> But a **puddle of water** no deeper than one finger, lying between the stones upon a paved street, offers a view downwards under the earth to as great a reach as the open heavens yawn on high, so that you seem to look down upon the clouds and heaven, and you see manifest objects miraculously buried beneath the earth.

*De Rerum Natura*, 4.414-419 (trans. W. H. D. Rouse)

Similarly, Apuleius uses ***conceptaculum aquae***, specifically in the context of recent rain:

> *Nam forte pluviae pridianae recens **conceptaculum aquae lutulentae** proximum conspicatus ...*
>
> It happened to have rained the day before, and I spotted a new
>   **puddle of muddy water** nearby ...

*Metamorphoses*, 7.20

---

ADDIT ***Stagnum***, on the other hand, seems to refer to something more like a pool of water or, at least, to a body of water larger than a puddle.

For example, Columella, writes of the importance of having a supply of water for pigs:

> *Sed cum omni quadrupedi per aestatem sitis sit infesta, tum suillo
>   maxime est inimica. Quare non ut capellam vel ovem, sic et hoc animal
>   bis ad aquam duci praecipimus: sed si fieri potest, iuxta flumen aut
>   **stagnum** per ortum Caniculae detineri*
>
> While thirst in the summer is pernicious to all quadrupeds, it is
>   specially hurtful to pigs. We, therefore, advise that they should not
>   be taken to water twice a day, like goats and sheep, but that, if
>   possible, they should be kept in the neighbourhood of a river or pool
>   at the time of the rising of the Dogstar

*On Agriculture*, 10.7.6

And here, speaking of fish ponds:

> ***Stagnum*** censemus eximie optimum, quod sic positum est, ut insequens
>   maris unda priorem submoveat, nec intra conseptum sinat remanere
>   veterem
>
> We consider that incomparably the best pond [for fish] is one which
>   is so situated that the incoming tide of the sea expels the water of
>   the previous tide and does not allow any stale water to remain within
>   the enclosure

8.17.1 See also 8.14.2 re: providing water for geese.

Here, in Caesar's *The African War*, he clearly refers to something other than a puddle:

> *Erat **stagnum** salinarum, inter quod et mare angustiae quaedam non
>   amplius mille et D passus intererant*
>
> There was a lagoon of salt water, separated from the sea by a certain
>   narrow strip of land not more than a mile and a half wide

Caesar, *The African War*, 80

Ovid, at *Metamorphoses*, 4.297 (and ff), uses *stagnum* of the pool in which Salmacis bathes her limbs.  And again, at 5.411 (but read 409 ff for story), he speaks of Cyane, standing *up to her waist* in a *stagnum*.

Lastly, Virgil specifies that they are deep:

> *Cocyti **stagna alta** vides Stygiamque paludem*
>
> [Anchises], you are looking at the deep pools of Cocytus and the
>   Stygian marsh,

*Aeneid*, 6.323

Answer (score 3):

*Lacuna* usually implies some kind of gap — if you like, a gap into which water runs and then stagnates, when it would become a puddle. The verb *stagno, -are* means 'form into pools', and the associated *stagnum* is any sort of standing water, of any shape or area.

I can't see any problem in using *stagnum*. It would surely cause no eyebrows to be raised if you were to modify it to a diminutive, say *stagnulum* or *stagnella*, either of which should be immediately understood.